# django get_or_create not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called snacks:

```
class Snack(models.Model):
    snack = models.CharField(max_length=9)
```

When I do

```
Snack.objects.get_or_create(snack="borsh")
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "restaurants_snack_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.
```

If I do it again, it's going to tell me the same thing except the key (that already exists) will be 7 and so on.

It's true that the key already exists, I'm wondering how can I make it pick a key that's the next one available?

Thanks in advance.

Jenia

Comment: which version of django ? if > 1.6, [check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.select_on_save)

Comment: Is that your *full* code? Are you sure you don't have any signals, or custom save methods, or a non-automatic primary key field?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476444/django-postgres-integrity-error-duplicate-key-how-to-fix) can help you.

Comment: By the way borsch is not a snack, it's a good meal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did some manual data importing, even if not, it's not problem with django, but with database auto increment sequence. Django has a management command that generates sql command to reset those:

```
./manage.py sqlsequencereset myapp1 myapp2
```

If you are using PostgreSQL you can just pipe it in like that:

```
./manage.py sqlsequencereset myapp1 myapp2 | psql
```

or `mysql` if you are using MySQL, but I haven't ried it.